# Del from database function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, sql-delete

JS file

```
"delete"  : function() {
              calEvent.id = id;
              id++;
              calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
              calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val());
              calEvent.title = titleField.val();
              calEvent.body = bodyField.val();

              //post to events.php
             $.post( "events.php", { action: "del", id: calEvent.id });


              $calendar.weekCalendar("removeEvent", calEvent.id);
              $dialogContent.dialog("close");
            }
```

Send ID to events.php and than in events.php handle recieve ID

```
<?php

$action = $_POST['action'];

if (!$link = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('agenda', $link)) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
}

if ($action == 'del')
{
    $id = $_POST['id']; 

    $del = "DELETE FROM meeting_rooms_calendar WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($del, $link);
    }
?>
```

Delete from database, but it not dropping my array in database. 
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Error messages? Are you sure the id is getting posted correctly?

Comment: I would suggest simply changing the database pass by adding a 1 at the end so it is wrong, to ensure you are getting the data posted over to that page. You should get ´Could not connect to mysql´.  Like @puelo says error messages will help you and us to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: That's the problem i think i dont get error message, i even dont know if the ID sends right. But i have a save method to and that works like it supposed to work

Comment: @JonPaulH if i do that it wont get my data from database so it wil be empty than i'm not enabled to "delete" aything

Comment: i post the codes in JSfiddle to get the whole code 
http://jsfiddle.net/6SK37/1/

Comment: Try to add "print_r($id);" to your delete method to see if the id getting posted correctly. On a other side note...Don't use "==" to compare string, use "===".